# Running apktool in a bash script

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, apktool

I am trying to write a bash script that decompiles several .apk files using apktool. Each apk file  is located in a subdirectory of the sample folder.

```
#!bin/bash


for item in $(ls samples);
do
        for apk in $(ls "samples/$item");
        do 
            echo ./apktool/apktool d "./samples/$item$apk" 
            $(./apktool/apktool d "./samples/$item$apk")
        done    
done
```

When I run the script I get the following output:

```
./apktool/apktool d ./samples/ADRD/53dc.apk*
Input file (./samples/ADRD/53dc.apk*) was not found or was not readable.
```

The input file error message is the standard for when apktool cannot find a file.  However, if I run the following command in the terminal the apktool will work correctly.

```
./apktool/apktool d ./samples/ADRD/53dc.apk*
```

I have changed the permissions of all the files located in the samples folder to rw for all users. I also have tried using sudo with the shell script, but this causes the script to hang. However, when I use sudo with the apktool in the command line it also hangs. Therefore, I am not sure if using sudo with apktool is doable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This script is so broken syntactically and semantically I don't even bother to point out all the errors and pitfalls... Anyway, why do you have an asterisk at the end of the filename? Is it really there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like this `ls` gives you an output with an asterisk * appended at the end of the apk filename, because the file is executable.

```
    for apk in $(ls "samples/$item");
```

This is not the default behaviour of `ls`, you are getting this probably because you have aliased `ls` to `ls -F` or similar. To bypass the alias, rewrite the line this way:

```
    for apk in $(\ls "samples/$item");
```

Notice the \ I added there.

BTW, is it normal that an apk file is executable? Perhaps you can remove the executable bit:

```
find samples -name '*.apk' -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

Also, possibly your script can be replaced with this one liner:

```
find samples -name '*.apk' -exec ./apktool/apktool d {} \;
```

Mind you, this is not exactly the same thing, because it may go deeper than two directories. If you need to limit the depth, that's possible too, see `man find`

Comment: Thanks! The asterisk was causing the problem.